# stack pointer offset for function arguments

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling

In building a gcc cross compiler I need to calculate the offset of the stack pointer which value is equal to the size of the block of the function's automatic variables.

That offset should be determined in the [Function Prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue).

(the value of N):

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, N
```

Is there any macro or function how I can calculate the offset?

Comment: So you are building a compiler? Then you have a data structure for each function parsed that contains information about its automatic variables and allignment. Now simply add the size of each variable to derive your N.

Comment: Yes I am. Which data structure contains information like that? I haven't found anything in the GCC Compiler Collection Internals book.

Comment: Check the code generation. That part must "know".